# Self Join Jpa Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

this code generate another [Item] table but i would crate a table that contains two fields that refer to the primary key of the item table, can anyone help me ?

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="itemComposition",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="parentItemId")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="childItemId")})
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
```

Comment: How can this code create another Item table? you can't have two tables with the same name. Please add more context.

Comment: this is a portion of the code found in the item class